# How to replace values using multiple conditions in Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I have the column: dataset["RSI_14D"]

I want to assign:

1 if serie's rows <= 20

-1 if serie's rows >= 80

0 if serie's rows 20<x<80

I tried:

```
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D"] >= 80, 'RSI_14D1'] = -1
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D"] <= 20, 'RSI_14D1'] = 1
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D1"] != 1 & -1, 'RSI_14D1'] = 0
```

but doesn't work

When I write:

```
dataset["RSI_14D1"][dataset["RSI_14D1"]  == -1  ]
```

it gives me 0 values even if there are 30+ rows with values >= 80

when I  write

```
dataset["RSI_14D1"][dataset["RSI_14D1"]  == 1  ]
```

it is ok, it replaced the values

Comment: you may be breaking your logic by setting all the 80+ to be -1 _before_ clearing the <=20

Comment: what does happen? how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Because when I type: dataset["RSI_14D1"][dataset["RSI_14D1"]  == -1  ] it gives me 0 values with "-1" even if there are 30+ values with values >= 80

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because for the last line of codes, the values of new column `RSI_14D1` are still not defined for rows of `RSI_14D` with values between 20 and 80.

You can replace the last line of code to:

```
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D"].between(20, 80,  inclusive='neither'), 'RSI_14D1'] = 0
```

or

```
dataset.loc[(dataset["RSI_14D"] > 20) & (dataset["RSI_14D"] < 80), 'RSI_14D1'] = 0
```

### Alternative Solution

Alternatively, if you want to handle the case differently for when `RSI_14D` values are between 20 and 80, you can do it by setting default value of `0` for new column `RSI_14D1`, as follows:

```
# Add this line at the front:
dataset['RSI_14D1'] = 0

# Keep your first 2 lines of codes:
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D"] >= 80, 'RSI_14D1'] = -1
dataset.loc[dataset["RSI_14D"] <= 20, 'RSI_14D1'] = 1
```

Comment: @TreesJin  Added alternative solution.  You can take a look.

Comment: @TreesJin  Pleased to help!  Remember that for programming, it is often easier to initialize a value for the most common scenario and add special handling for special cases.